# Which StarCraft units are not present in Wings of Liberty?

Tags: starcraft-2

Where can I find a list of *StarCraft* and *StarCraft: Brood War* units (with unit spells/abilities) which are not present in *StarCraft II: Wings of Liberty* (counting both campaign and multiplayer)?

Comment: Do you mean units from the original Stracraft and SC:BroodWar?

Comment: Are you counting SC2 campaign units or just multiplayer ones (Firebat, Vulture, Wraith, Vessel...)?  I think there are even more "old" units available in the editor, hence SC2:BW.

Comment: Sorry, I meant SC:BroodWar and SC2 campaign+multiplayer. Updated my question.

Comment: It's not a very useful question because even the units that are the same have been changed so much. Carriers in sc2 are not the carriers in sc1 for example. What do you want this information for?

Comment: @tenfour I would like to have a basic knowledge and understanding of what is missing. Many times in StarCraft-related discussions people refer to SC1 units and I don't even know what these units are. Apart from that I believe that some may still appear in the future expansions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Many more units show up in the single player campaign than appear in multiplayer. The following, however, do not appear at all.

### Zerg

- Defiler
- Guardian
- Devourer
- old-style queen.
- old-style infested terran.

### Terran

- Valkyrie

### Protoss

- Reaver
- Dragoon
- Dark Archon
- Corsair
- Arbiter
- Shuttle

Comment: Don't forget the Terran Dropship. (The Medivac is similar, but it's more of a hybrid between BW's Medic and Dropship).

Comment: Another: Scourge

Comment: @tenfour Scourge *is* present in the campaign.

Comment: @Wikwocket Regular, non-medic dropships are also present in the campaign.

Comment: Guardian = Brood Lord?

Comment: @ClarityForce - No. Guardian was a Mutalisk evolution. Brood Lord is a Corruptor evolution. They *are* quite similar, however.